# wget: convert links offline

Tags: wget

Suppose I was downloading a site, have not finished the download, but wish to convert links already. Is it possible?

Normally - after the download is finished - wget converts links to local - if -k option was set.

Comment: I wouldn't try manipulating the downloaded data until `wget` finishes downloading it.